# enzyme shallow calls imported function when passed wrong parameters

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that I am writing automated tests for. I want to test a method of this component. THe purpose if this test if if the method will call an imported function when passed the wrong parameters.

This is my component (I removed the non-relevant code):

```
//Util
import { getMenu } from '../utils/request';

const Dashboard = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        let today = new Date();
        if (today.getDay() == 6) {
            today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2);
        } else if (today.getDay() == 0) {
            today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return {
            selectedDate: today.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
        }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        getMenu(this.state.selectedDate, (data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                this.setState({
                    error: data.error
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    dailyMenu: data.dailyMenu,
                    loading: false
                })
            }
        })

    },

    handleDateChange(date) {
        var newDate =  date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        if(newDate !== this.state.selectedDate) {
            getMenu(newDate, (data) => {
                if (data.error) {
                    this.setState({
                        error: data.error
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        dailyMenu: data.dailyMenu,
                        loading: false,
                        selectedDate: newDate
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div className="Dashboard">
                    <div className="Dashboard-body">
                        <Sidebar dateClick={this.handleDateChange}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Dashboard;
```

I am mocking the getMenu function using `jest.mock`:

```
// Components
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';

// Utils
import { getMenu } from '../utils/request';
jest.mock('../utils/request', () => ({getMenu: jest.fn()}))
```

Then I have written two tests. The first one passes different dates, the second one passes the same date. So in the second case the getMenu mock should not get called. But for both tests I get the result that the function was called one time:

```
  it('handleDateChange should call getMenu when NOT passed state date', ()=> {
    const dashboard = shallow(<Dashboard/>);
    const today = new Date();
    const longAgo = new Date(1).toISOString().substring(0, 10);

    dashboard.setState({ selectedDate: longAgo });
    dashboard.instance().handleDateChange(today);
    expect(getMenu).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('handleDateChange should NOT call getMenu when passed state date', ()=> {
    const dashboard = shallow(<Dashboard/>);
    const today = new Date();
    const selectedDate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

    dashboard.setState({ selectedDate: selectedDate });
    dashboard.instance().handleDateChange(today);
    expect(getMenu).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
```

So I did some console logs and so far everything seems as expected:

```
console.log(today.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
console.log(dashboard.state('selectedDate'));

console.log(today.toISOString().substring(0, 10) !== selectedDate);
```

This outputs:

```
2017-01-12
2017-01-12
false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `expect(getMenu).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);` should be `expect(getMenu).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` because it has been already called once above.

Comment: Correct, changing the order of the tests eliminates the issue. Thanks a lot. You can write up this as an anwser, and I will accept it